# Building and using shared libraries with bjam

Tags: linux, gcc, ubuntu, bjam, boost-build

Using bjam on ubuntu, I am building a c++ shared library and trying to use it in an executable. I have to build as shared since it wont link as static (lots of undefined references arise). Thats fine.

Two related problems:

1) Using a heirarchy of Jamfiles, my exe project (testServerHub) has a dependency on the shared library (pythonManager). Here's the Jamfile for the exe:

```
echo "Compiling serverHub//test" ;

# declare project name
project serverHub//testServerHub
    : build-dir ../_gcc/intermediate 
    ;

# build unit-test using these source files, dependent libraries and settings
exe testServerHub
    : # Source
      ..\\..\\..\\common\\0_8_1\\test\\runner.cpp
      successfulTest.cpp

      # Dependent libraries by path and project name
      ../controller/pythonManager//pythonManager 
      /boost//unit_test_framework

    : # Settings
      <link>shared
    ;

install ..\\bin : testServerHub ;
```

And here's my lib Jamfile:

```
echo "Compiling serverHub/controller//pythonManager" ;

# declare project name
project serverHub/controller//pythonManager     
    : requirements 
      <define>URTH_SERVERHUB
    : build-dir ../../_gcc/intermediate 
    ;

# build library using these source files and settings
lib pythonManager 
    : ../../../../common/0_8_1/controller/pythonManager/pythonManager.cpp
      ../../../../common/0_8_1/controller/pythonManager/cppInterfaceBase.cpp
      cppInterfaceServerHub.cpp
      /boost/python//boost_python
      /user-config//python
    : <link>shared
    ;

# copy and rename
install ../../lib : pythonManager ;
```

If I run 'bjam pythonManager' the pythonManager shared library is built and copied to my project lib folder (by the final install command). However if I run 'bjam test', both testServerHub and pythonManager are built, but the libpythonManager.so is not copied to the project lib folder - the install command doens't run!

2) Okay, so as a temporary workaround, I build libpythonManager.so first and then build testServerHub executable. Both compile and link. At runtime, the executable complains about not being able to find libpythonManager.so. Not a great surprise since the runtime linker doesn't know about my project lib folder. How do I tell it to look in a certain directory for shared libraries? or how do I install libpythonManager.so into /usr/local/lib if the install command has no effect on dependent library builds?

Thank you very much

Si

Comment: One approach is to use unit-test rule instead of exe rule. In this case, shared libraries are somehow linked at runtime.

This doesn't help my main executable though. What is the proper way to do this on linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you could use `<install-dependencies>on` in the exe Jamfile, like in

```
install ..\\bin : testServerHub : <install-dependencies>on <install-type>LIB ;
```

This will install all the libraries (LIB) on which the exe depends.

See eg http://www.boost.org/doc/tools/build/doc/html/bbv2/tasks/installing.html as a reference.